# How to disable Android-Studio auto focus on emulator, after each run?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio  `Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2`, each time I run the app, after the installation and launching the APK file, it focuses automatically on the emulator!

It's so annoying especially when you're coding simultaneously and it tries to bind the keys you've just pressed into the emulator!

So how can I disable this marvelous feature?

Comment: Did you come to a solution? I've found this report https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/275455841 claiming this issue has been fixed, but I cannot tell what might be the solution.